# Display radio button with dropdown user selection

Tags: django

I would like to create two fields: a radio button and dropdown
radio button will populate given choice and dropdown will pull from the DB. 
Getting stuck with displaying the radio and fetching value

Should I be using modelform or form? I would like to store data in DB when radio button selection is down with dropdown value and like to take that value to display a case types.

MODEL.py

```
class Selections(models.Model):

    roletype = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=None)
    LOCATIONS = (('DC1','DC1'), ('DC2', 'DC2'), ('DC3', 'DC3'))
    location = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=LOCATIONS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roletype
```

FORMs.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Selections
class SelectionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ROLES = (('1','Type1'),('2','Type2'),('3', 'Type3'))
    roletype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Selections
        fields = ['roletype','location']
```

VIEWs.py

```
## VIEW: Populate dropdown to select Data center
def get_role_dc_data(request, *args, **kwargs):

    location = Selections.objects.get(id=0) # List of objects
    roletype = Selections.objects.get(id=1) # List of objects

    context = { 'location': location, 'roletype': roletype }

    return render(request, 'selections/view.html', context)
```

view.html

```
<form method="post" action=/viewselections/> {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
      <th>
          {% for radio_input in context.roletype %}
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="{{ radio_input.id }}" value="{{ radio_input.id }}">
          {% endfor %}
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="fieldWrapper" align="center" id="mainselection">
          <select name="location">
            <option selected="selected">Select an the site</option>
            {% for instance in context.location %}
            <option >{{ instance.location }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Not able to fetch the value. not sure if this is correct way
Also once the user selected the selections, how to display the return data and store in DB.

Comment: I think you should find and follow a Django forms tutorial to see how they work. You're missing several things, especially where the form isn't being used in your view or template.

Comment: i have added the form info and updated the post

Comment: I meant that your code is missing several elements which make Django forms work. Just search for "Django forms tutorial" and you'll find many wonderful results which will teach you.